# tkinter module crash when there is while loop inside

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import winsound
from os import path
import getpass



amazonBot = Tk()
amazonBot.geometry("300x300")
amazonBot.title('Amazon oto order bot')
username = getpass.getuser()

Label(amazonBot, text="Item Link").grid(row=0)


def inputsText():
    linkInputText = linkInput.get()
    
    

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # add your chrome profile path (you can find it with texting )
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options) # Add your chrome-driver path

    buyingStatus = True

    while(buyingStatus):

        try:
            driver.get(linkInputText)
            print(driver.title)
            beGreedy = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('quantity'))
            beGreedy.select_by_value('1')
            addCart = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-stack").submit()
            completeTheShopping = driver.find_element_by_id("hlb-ptc-btn-native").click()
            

            buyNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/span/input").click()
            Label(amazonBot, text="Item Found").grid(row=2)
            freq = 500
            dur = 2000
            winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
            print("ITEM FOUND")
            buyingStatus = False


        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Item doesn't exist")
            driver.refresh()



linkInput = Entry(amazonBot,width=20)
linkInput.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(amazonBot,text="Start Bot",command=inputsText).grid(row=3,column=1)




amazonBot.mainloop()
```

Hi guys have a good day.I am trying to make amazon auto order bot with selenium + tkinter but there is one problem.When i start to program inside of while loop work properly but tkinter gui get crush.I guess
"amazonBot.mainloop()" function never work because of while loop but i dont know what to do.

Comment: There might be an exception (problem) in your selenium logic, so use try/except statements to handle that, or make the bot as a console application first, instead of using Tkinter GUI. The GUI crashes when there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: @BryanOakley Actually `buyingStatus` change when product bought.